# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "lstm" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

Tags: nlp, lstm, word-embedding

I am struggling to make Embedding layer play nicely with LSTM.
I am feeding one-hot data in batches into this model, and it works well until I add an embedding layer.

I am receiving this error: `ValueError: Input 0 of layer "lstm" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, None, 26, 256)`

26 is the `self.source.enc_vocab_len`

```
self.latent_dim = 256

encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, self.source.enc_vocab_len))
encoder_embedding = Embedding(self.source.enc_vocab_len + 1, self.latent_dim)(encoder_inputs)
encoder_lstm = LSTM(self.latent_dim, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder_lstm(encoder_embedding)
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

# Define decoder
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, self.source.dec_vocab_len))
decoder_embedding = Embedding(self.source.dec_vocab_len + 1, self.latent_dim)(decoder_inputs)
decoder_lstm = LSTM(self.latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_embedding, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = Dense(self.source.dec_vocab_len + 1, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

# Define the model that maps input sequence to output sequence
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
return model
```

Please help me understand the solution